# Nintex Group By workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, nintex-workflow

I am having a problem trying to get Nintex to group by and send out an update email to that group.

In short I have a list with two fields, primary contact and who their account is.  I want a workflow that will group all the accounts listed to the individual contact and send out an email monthly to that individual for  them to if they still cover their accounts…  I’m new to Nintex and tried a few things and was not able to get them to group together.  Any ideas?

Here is an example of the data:

```
Customer   Account #    Sales Rep
Dons Bakery 121     Dave Williams
Dons Bakery 131     Dave Williams
Dons Bakery 140     Dave Williams
Dons Bakery 201     Dave Williams
Spa West    500     Mario Davis
Spa West    501     Mario Davis
Spa West    800     Mario Davis
Spa West    1512        Mario Davis
Spa West    1800        Mario Davis
Spa West    1801        Mario Davis
Spa West    1802        Mario Davis
Spa West    1854        Mario Davis
Spa West    1895        Mario Davis
Spa West    1900        Mario Davis
Spa West    20000       Mario Davis
Atlantic     100        Janet Rogers
Atlantic     150        Janet Rogers
Atlantic     151        Janet Rogers
Atlantic    168         Janet Rogers
Atlantic    175         Janet Rogers
Atlantic      2         Janet Rogers
```

As you can each account number is unique ( no rhyme or reason to the numbers), and each sales rep only serves one customer.  My goal is at the end of month to send out an email to say Fave Williams, and ask him to confirm that those account numbers are still accurate ( they have a tendency to change) and still corresponds to those sales reps.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, need to use Query List
Here is a great example:

http://thijsdeschepper.be/?p=854